# Using Pandas to concatenate values in a column and sum corresponding values in another column

Tags: sum, concatenation, grouping

For example, if i have a dataset in the first table below....

| Name | Code | Thickness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CH1 | 3 | 0.5 |
| CH1 | 3 | 0.3 |
| CH1 | 4 | 0.4 |
| CH1 | 3 | 0.2 |
| CH1 | 5 | 0.6 |
| CH1 | 5 | 0.4 |

.... and i want to achieve the result in the next table by grouping by the "Code" column and summing the "Thickness" column

| Name | Code | Thickness | Grp_Thinckness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH1 | 3 | 0.5 | 0.8 |
| CH1 | 3 | 0.3 | 0.8 |
| CH1 | 4 | 0.4 | 0.4 |
| CH1 | 3 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| CH1 | 5 | 0.6 | 1.0 |
| CH1 | 5 | 0.4 | 1.0 |

How do I go about this?

Comment: There are 3 rows with `Code = 3`. Why is `Grp_Thickness = 0.8, 0.8, 0.2`. Should they all be `1.0`?

Comment: You are right but i just don't want to sum up all same code numbers together but same consecutive code numbers. That's why the sum of the first two Codes (3) = 0.8. The next code = 4 before you have code 3 again, which is 0.2 in thickness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a gap-and-island problem. Anytime the `Code` changes, it creates a new island. You can solve these problems with a `cumsum`:

```py
s = (df["Code"] != df["Code"].shift()).cumsum()
df["Grp_Thickness"] = df.groupby(s)["Thickness"].transform("sum")
```